# How to appropriately restore an android app from and back to a fragment after a system destroy

Tags: android, android-fragments, restore

Simply speaking:

> MyApp (main activity) -> MyApp (2nd Activity with fragment attached)
>   -> home -> AnotherApp -> MyApp.

Before AnotherApp switched back to MyApp, I took quite a while and system destroy happened. MyApp started from the main activity again, this is not good experience. And I know how to restore app using `savedInstanceState`, but this seems only applicable for all action in same activity.

So my question is: For an app, the last seen is a fragment in an activity, how to save or mark anything, so that when app restored from system destroy, onCreate() of main activity can pick up the variable then go back to the last seen activity with that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, try in the MainActivity code:

```
@override
public void onCreate(@Nullable savedInstance){
    if(savedInstance != null){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

And in AcitivityB, save what you want overriding the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate)`Method and restore them by overriding the `onViewStateRestored` Method. Give it a shot and lemme know.

Comment: never try this way, but before this, how can I know the last seen fragment is from ActivityB, while not from ActivityC or others? This is also a key I want to figure out .